# Registrar IP de quienes ingresan a la web pero solo la pagina principal

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo que se encarga de registrar la direccion IP, fecha, hora, sistema operativo, de quienes ingresan a la pagina web. Y funciona bien.

PERO lo que yo deseo es que solo me registre esa informacion cuando ingresen a la pagina principal **index.php**  y NO me registre esa informacion cuando naveguen por las otras paginas del sitio.

Para ingresar a  mi sitio siempre sera por la direccion **misitio.com/index.php**

Y al navegar por las diferentes paginas de mi sitio la direcion siempre sera
**misitio.com/index.php?**  Y lo unico que cambiara sera la ruta que va despues del signo de interrogacion **"?"**

Al utilizar este codigo, lo que hace es registrar esa informacion por cualquier pagina que se visite, y eso NO es lo que deseo, solo quiero que me registre la informacion cuando se ingresa unicamente a **misitio.com/index.php**

Que linea debo ajustar en el codigo para que eso sea posible ?

```
<?php
$Fichero = "archivo.txt"; //nombre del fichero donde se guardan los informes.
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; //guarda en la variable el ip 
$fecha = date("Y-m-d;H:i:s"); //fecha y hora (por lo general del servidor) 
$sistema = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //Esto nos genera varios datos del navegador y del sistema operativo 
$conproxy = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; //En caso de usar proxy para esconderse aqui estaria el ip real
$log = "FECHA: $fecha SISTEMA: $sistema IP: $ip IPPROXY: $conproxy \x0D\x0A"; 
$fp = fopen($Fichero, "a" ); 
fwrite($fp, $log); 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Comment: Podrias con una funcion abrir el archivo de registro y verificar que esa direccion ip no este registrada antes de realizar el guardado de datos

Comment: La idea es que si despues de navegar por las diferentes paginas, vuelve otra vez al index.php, debe registrar nuevamente la IP. Y esa funcion como se haria? pero si esa funcion verifica que la ip ya esta alli, y si esa persona vuelve despues, y no registra la IP, entonces no me serviria

Comment: Comprendo, en ese caso, el codigo que has puesto es el codigo de tu index.php? O hay mas codigo?

Comment: Prueba con la siguiente linea en tu codigo

if (substr_count(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "PHP_SELF", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), substr(__FILE__, (strrpos(__FILE__, '/') + 1)))) {
           //Tu codigo aca
}

En el index.php y adentro pones lo que vas a hacer PD: Lo que esta en Negrita, cambialo por dos _ seguidos

Comment: @ivan botero el codigo que puse esta dentro del index.php lo puse al final. No entiendo como poner tu codigo

Comment: Mira: http://pastebin.com/cEqBKZ9J

Comment: Gracias ivan. NO entiendo eso de lo que esta en negrita cambiarlo por dos. Por dos que ? He copiado el codigo exactamente como lo dejaste en pastebin, y no funciona, no me registra nada.

Answer (score 1):

por acá te dejo un código ya listo, te recomiendo que uses una base mysql, el código te lo dejo hasta la variable getRealIP de allí solo te queda almacenarlo en la base, supongo que eso es mucho mas sencillo, si no busca como almacenar una variable en una base de datos mysql, a mi manera de ver eso es mucho mas útil que almacenar en un archivo, este código lo pegas en la pagina donde quieres registrar la ip, recuerda que debe estar en extensión .php, espero te sirva, un saludo a todos:

```
<?php

function getRealIP()
{

   if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '' )
   {
      $client_ip =
         ( !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            :
            ( ( !empty($_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
               $_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']
               :
               "unknown" );

              $entries = split('[, ]', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);

              reset($entries);
              while (list(, $entry) = each($entries))
              {
         $entry = trim($entry);
     if ( preg_match("/^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/", $entry, $ip_list) )
     {
        $private_ip = array(
              '/^0\./',
              '/^127\.0\.0\.1/',
              '/^192\.168\..*/',
              '/^172\.((1[6-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))\..*/',
              '/^10\..*/');

        $found_ip = preg_replace($private_ip, $client_ip, $ip_list[1]);

        if ($client_ip != $found_ip)
        {
           $client_ip = $found_ip;
           break;
        }
     }
  }
}
else
{
  $client_ip =
     ( !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        :
        ( ( !empty($_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ?
           $_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']
           :
           "unknown" );
}

return $client_ip;

}

echo "Su Inúmero IP es: ".getRealIP();

?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Ajuste un poco tu codigo para que se viera bien en la respuesta. Podrias mirar [answer] y tambien explicar un poco que hace este codigo?

Comment: Hey Gracias!! vere como responder! un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar la variable de entorno QUERY_STRING que pertenece a la global $_SERVER. Esta variable te devuelve el query string que esta definido en la url a la que el usuario esta ingresando. Si $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] esta vacio se podria suponer que estan en el home. Otra alternativa seria usar el mismo metodo con una whitelist de las secciones donde no quieras que se ejecute el proceso que guarda las IPs y solo dispararlo si no se encuentran tus palabras claves en el query string.

Ejemplo / Validar que el usuario llegue a index.php sin agregar ningun parametro.

```
if (empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){
    $Fichero = "archivo.txt"; //nombre del fichero donde se guardan los informes.
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; //guarda en la variable el ip 
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d;H:i:s"); //fecha y hora (por lo general del servidor) 
    $sistema = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //Esto nos genera varios datos del navegador y del sistema operativo 
    $conproxy = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; //En caso de usar proxy para esconderse aqui estaria el ip real
    $log = "FECHA: $fecha SISTEMA: $sistema IP: $ip IPPROXY: $conproxy \x0D\x0A"; 
    $fp = fopen($Fichero, "a" ); 
    fwrite($fp, $log); 
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

Comment: la verdad es que poco entiendo de esos codigos. por favor podrias indicarme en que parte del codigo debo insertar la linea o las lineas

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, proba el script y volve a leer la respuesta. Lo mas conveniente es que hagas un echo de $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] en tu index.php y navegues por tus diferentes secciones para que veas como va cambiando el valor de la variable, deberias adaptar esta logica a tu script contemplando todas tus secciones.

Comment: Gracias Max...Probe el codigo, pero me sigue registrando todo. Mi pagina es un foro, y por consiguiente son foros, subforos, temas, mensajes, etc..y como veras hacer exepciones a cada uno de ellos es bastante complicado. No habra otra manera de hacerlo, dando alguna instruccion en el codigo para que solo me registre cuando ingresen solo al index.php, y no cuando cuando ingresen a index.php ? ya que lo unico que varia es lo que va despues del signo de interrogacion, y todas las paginas siempren llevan el index.php?xxxx

Comment: Hola Samuel, el script que te pase hace exactamente lo que decis. Te recomiendo que agregues un echo de $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] en tu index.php y navegues por varias secciones volviendo al home para ver que te muestra en cada caso. Esto te lo digo no para que armes una lista con todas las secciones si no para que verifiques si a tu home no esta llegando algun parametro extra q confunda al script y ejecute el script de todos modos. En otras palabras deberias ver que es lo que devuelve $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] estando parado en el home y usar ese string para solo ejecutar la funcion en ese caso

Comment: Gracias...por favor podrias decirme como hago el echo, no tengo muy claro como armarlo.

Comment: Bastaria con que agregues a tu codigo la siguiente linea: 
echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

Podrias añadir algun caracter mas para identificar si esta variable llega vacia, algo como:
echo "Valor devuelto: ".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

Comment: lo agregue pero me sigue registrando todo

Comment: Enviame por favor un link de tu sitio para poder reproducirlo.

Comment: lo estoy trabajando en localhost, y aun no lo tengo en la nube